# How do I output a time variable into my timezone?

Tags: php, wordpress, date, timezone, echo

I am currently using Wordpress, and an element of user_registered returns the time of registration of the user.
I have set the correct timezone, but don't know how to get the user_registered output to match my current time.
So far, this is what I have.

```
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');


    $users = get_users();

    foreach( $users as $user ) {

        $udata = get_userdata( $user->ID );

        $registered = $udata->user_registered;

        printf( '%s member since %s<br>', $udata->data->display_name, date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( $registered ) ) );
    }


echo('date below <br>');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The date default timezone indeed changes the timezone (last echo)
However, what I want to change is the output of $registered. (which is the stored time).

How do I globally change the way the time is being displayed when called? In other words if I call for the date/timestamp through plugin or direct, it will always give me the output of America/Los_Angeles.

Thanks in advance. I'm a noob.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime` functions.
http://php.net/manual/ro/datetime.settimezone.php

Your code can be something like this:

```
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');


    $users = get_users();

    foreach( $users as $user ) {

        $udata = get_userdata( $user->ID );

        $registered = $udata->user_registered;

        $date = new DateTime(date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( $registered )), new DateTimeZone('UTC')); //replace UTC with whatever is the timezone that the data was stored in
        $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

        printf( '%s member since %s<br>', $udata->data->display_name,  $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
    }


echo('date below <br>');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**EDIT**: Timezone conversion implies that an original timezone and a target timezone is specified. So in this case

`date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`

specifies the target timezone. But you still need to specify the original timezone for the values retrieved from the db. WP has a built in function that gets the timezone 
`get_option('timezone_string')`

So in your original example you can use a simpler approach with just specifying the original timezone in the `strtotime()` function.

```
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');


    $users = get_users();

    foreach( $users as $user ) {

        $udata = get_userdata( $user->ID );

        $registered = $udata->user_registered;


        printf( '%s member since %s<br>', $udata->data->display_name, date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( $registered ." ".get_option('timezone_string')) ) );
    }
```

Comment: the $registered is just for echo purposes.... Does it change all output when user_registered is called? Thanks.

Comment: @Theo I've edited my answer. You should provide a original timezone value for the time values you want to convert.